# My function stopped working when I added a toggle in my boolean. Why?

Tags: javascript, boolean, toggle

My function Submit is working normally, my else if is doing an alert but when I try to replace that alert with a function toggle to hide the first step and to show the second step of my quiz it's blocking.

My code in HTML

```
  <div id="registration" class="container">
        <h2>Welcome to Badoo quiz</h2>
        <div class="main">
          <form class="form" method="post" action="#">
            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name">
            <input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Last name">
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="checkbox" id="agreed"> Email Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            <button id="register" value="Register">Register</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

My code in CSS, I made sure that my step one registration ID was set to block and the other steps of the quiz with display : none.

```
#rule, #quizContainer, #final {
  display: none;
}

#registration {
  display: block;
}
```

My JS code, I've create a function that hide and show so I can reapply them for later step.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // toggle
  function hide(x){
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
  };

  function show(y){
    if (y.style.display === "none") {
        y.style.display = "block";
    }
  };

  //SIGN UP//
  function signUp() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var agreed = document.getElementById('agreed');
    var registration = document.getElementById('registration');
    var rule = document.getElementById('rule');
    var x = registration;
    var y = rule;
      if (name === '' || lastName === '' || email === '' ) {
        alert("Please fill all fields.");
      } else if (agreed.checked === true) {
        hide(x);
      } else {
        alert ("Tick the box please!");
      }
    };
document.getElementById('register').onclick = function () {
  signUp()
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following conditional statement from your code:

```
if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
}
```

Using `element.style.property === "value"` only tests values for inline styles, meaning styles that were included directly in the HTML with a style attribute or styles added with JavaScript.

Since your display property was set with CSS, the inline value is empty and the conditional returns `false`.

To test styles that were set with CSS, use this instead:

```
getComputedStyle(x).display === "block"
```

If you prefer to still use `x.style.display === "block"` for your conditional statement, then you can put the styles directly in your HTML. This is considered bad practice, however, as it decreases separation of concerns and makes your code harder to maintain.

You can also set the styles via JavaScript by adding something like this to the top of your ready event callback function:

```
var registration = document.getElementById('registration');
var x = registration;
x.style.display = "block";
```

Note: either method will allow your boolean toggle to work properly.

Comment: I see, if I wanted to use the function that I wrote (x.style.display), then I would need to add the style directly in my html div right? Like this:
<div id=registration style="display:block"></div>

Comment: @KellyTran Yes, that will work, but is not best practice. I have edited my answer to address this.